# tmux ctrl-k to erase the line from cursor to end of line

Tags: zsh, tmux

Outside tmux I use ctrl-k to erase the line in my terminal with zsh from the cursor to end of line. When I'm in tmux it doesn't work. Below is my `tmux.conf`:

```
set-option -g prefix C-a

# From: https://goo.gl/LmdY5K
set -g set-titles on
set -g set-titles-string "#T"

set -g status-right '%Y%m%d | %H:%M '

setw -g mode-keys vi

bind C-a last-window
bind | split-window -h
bind - split-window -v
bind m command-prompt -p "join pane from:"  "join-pane -s '%%'"
#bind s command-prompt -p "send pane to:"  "join-pane -t '%%'"
bind s choose-session
bind a send-prefix

# Make tmux forward-word and backward-word with CTRL+arrow
# See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15988701/1679629
set-window-option -g xterm-keys on
```

What is going on and how to fix that?

Comment: Using `tmux` under `bash`, the C-k shortcut works as it always does under a non-tmux shell prompt. Not sure why it doesn't work for you under `zsh`.

Comment: It's up to you to tell the rest of the world what is going on.  We're not telepathic.  You need to tell us explicitly, in the question, what happens when you press control+k.  We know *what you did* and *what you expect as a result*.  But you haven't said *what the computer is doing instead*.  Always follow the standard litany when asking for help.  And for good measure, show people the output of `bindkey "^K"` in your question, too.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and realized that `bindkey "^K"` returns `"^K" self-insert` in tmux and `"^K" kill-line` otherwise. After adding explicitly

```
bindkey \^K kill-line
```

to my `.zshrc` it works

Comment: (to whomever changed the `bindkey` to `bind-key`, the command to configure key bindings in zsh is `bindkey`, there's no `bind-key` command in zsh, (though there is a `bind-key` directive in `tmux` configuration files))

Comment: It would be interesting to know what changed the binding of `^K` from it's default of `kill-line`. I suspect it's rather that `zsh` was put in `vi` mode instead of `emacs` mode. Possibly because `$EDITOR` or `$VISUAL` contains `vi`. In which case the correct approach would be to add `bindkey -e`  (to get `emacs` style editing) in `~/.zshrc`